# What to do after being passed over for a promotion

Tags: career-development

I was hoping for a promotion in the company I work with. I was quite confident it would be given to me, because those in charge told me I would probably get the promotion.

I believe I have done the best I can at my current position and that I am ready for new tasks - I was fit for the promotion. Still, the promotion was eventually given to one of my co-workers. Things for me have not changed at all on the job, and I am feeling quite disappointed and disillusioned.

I am not a difficult employee and I do my current job efficiently. But, I hoped to become at least a General Accountant before I leave my current job. Maybe God has better plans for me...

How do I overcome the pain of being passed over, and where should I go from here?

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-have-an-agony-aunt-tag

Comment: Edited to add what I assume is your question (though it may not show up for a bit). If it is not your question please feel free to edit it to make it into your question.

Comment: Hey promilkid, and welcome to [workplace.se]! It is a bit unclear what your specific problem is, or how you want to solve it. You got passed over for a promotion, but obviously we can't change that part. Are you struggling with being motivated to work hard? To face your coworker? To face your manager? Without know what the issue is and what sort of solution you're looking for, this is a bit difficult to answer. Could you please [edit] your question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am currently an Accountant in a subsidiary of a well-known oil refinery in the Philippines. I have been employed for 1 year and 2 months and this is my first job. Currently, there are vacancies in General Accounting section and Tax section. The one who told me to replace her is in General Accounting and proposed it to our Head. Eventually, our Head Accountant said I might be transferred to Tax Accounting in lieu of the other. But still, it is tentative and not final.

Answer (score 4):

It can be painful to be passed over for a promotion. It's happened to me before, and it's never fun.

First things first, you will definitely want to privately talk things over with your manager. Avoid expressing anger, and definitely do not trash talk or rant about the co-worker who did get the promotion, though it's okay to say that you were disappointed about being passed over. Overall, you should stay positive, and the focus should really be on what your future career path will be with the company and what you need to do to stay on that path. At the very least, your manager should provide you with recommendations that, if reasonable, you should try to follow.

At that point, you really have 2 choices.

1. You can stick with the company. Follow the recommendations that your manager gives you, and look for the next promotion opportunity within the company.
2. Start your search for a new job. If the recommendations that your manager gives are, in your opinion, too unreasonable or the timeline of the career path seems too long to you (or if you seem to just have hit a glass ceiling), go ahead and start your search. You may actually find a position of better rank at a different company.

Answer (score -7):

> How do I overcome the pain of being passed over?

Not easy. Best thing to do IMO is just to focus on your current tasks and do the best you can with them.

Hopefully, you don't hate your work, and find some gratification from it. Focus on that, and put the past behind you. Everyone wants to be promoted, but there are only so many spots available. It wasn't your turn yet - that's business; that's Life. If you are fit, your time will come.

It's also important to realize that not getting promoted doesn't necessarily mean your employers are dissatisfied with you, or that your work is somehow deficient. Many factors are involved in such decisions: "Office politics", personalities, etc,  are very important regarding who gets moved up, and when. Maybe they just didn't like color of your tie that day! (Yes, those things happen...) From a distance, it's very hard to say, so don't feel so bad about it.

Another thing you **might** consider is approaching those who mentioned that you were apparently in line for the promotion, and asking them, **very tactfully and delicately**, "What happened?". You need to proceed with **great care** if you choose to explore this path: You could be viewed as arrogant, jealous or overly ambitious by your superiors for questioning them in such manner, thereby setting yourself back even further. You have to know the "playing field" well - have a very good grasp of your relationship with your superiors, and your standing in the firm - to undertake such a discussion.

> where should I go from here?

You'd need to tell us a good deal more about your present situation to expect a good answer on that. For example: If you're 25 and have been on the job for two years, the answer will be entirely different than if you're 40 and have been on the job for ten years.

Comment: And this answer is bad because...?